# ReflectionException Class app\Repositories\MailMessageRepository does not exist

Tags: laravel, datatable, repository

i'm having trouble accessing a repository, I can't call functions. I'm trying to integrate a softdelete button on my MailMessages datatable but I can't use the repository, I recived the following message:

> ReflectionException Class app\Repositories\MailMessageRepository does
> not exist

My MailMessageController

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\DataTables\MailMessageDataTable;
use App\Http\Requests\MailMessageRequest;
use app\Repositories\MailMessageRepository;
use App\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DataTables;
use PulkitJalan\Google\Facades\Google;

class MailMessageController extends Controller
{
    protected $mailMessageRepository;

    /**
     * UserController constructor.
     * @param $mailmessageRepository
     */
    public function __construct(mailmessageRepository $mailmessageRepository)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->MailMessageRepository = $mailmessageRepository;
    }


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(MailMessageDataTable $MailMessageDataTable)
    {
        return $MailMessageDataTable->render('mailmessage.index');
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
     //   $MailMessage = $this->MailMessageRepository;
        return view('mailmessage.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(MailMessageRequest $request)
    {
        $MailMessage = $this->MailMessageRepository->saveMailMessage($request);
        return redirect()->route('MailMessage.show', ["id" => $MailMessage->id])
            ->with(["message" => __('messages.create.success')]);
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\MailMessage  $mailMessage
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $MailMessage = MailMessage::find($id);
        return view('MailMessage.show', ['MailMessage' => $MailMessage]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\MailMessage  $mailMessage
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $MailMessage = MailMessage::find($id);
        return view('MailMessage.edit', ['MailMessage' => $MailMessage]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\MailMessage  $mailMessage
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $MailMessage = MailMessage::find($id);
        $MailMessage->type = $request->type;
        $MailMessage->description = $request->description;
        $MailMessage->from_value = $request->from_value;
        $MailMessage->to_value = $request->to_value;
        $MailMessage->update();
        return redirect('MailMessage/' .$MailMessage->id)->with(["message" => __('messages.edit.success')]);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\MailMessage  $mailMessage
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $MailMessage = $this->MailMessageRepository->getMessagebyId($id, true);
        if ($MailMessage->trashed()) {
            $MailMessage->restore();
        }else{
            $MailMessage->delete();
        }

        return redirect()->route('MailMessage.index')
            ->with(["message" => __('messages.update.success')]);
    }
    public function digest_report(MailMessage $mailMessage)
    {

    }
}
```

my MailMessageRepository

```
    <?php


namespace App\Repositories;

use App\User;
use App\MailMessage;
use App\Enums\MailMessageType;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class MailMessageRepository
{

    public function getMessage($id, $trashed = false)
    {
        if($trashed){
            return MailMessage::withTrashed();
        }
        return MailMessage;
    }

    public function getMessageById($id, $trashed = false)
    {

        if ($trashed) {
            return MailMessage::withTrashed()->with('roles')
                ->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
        }

        return MailMessage->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    }

    public function deleteMailMessage($id)
    {
        $MailMessage = MailMessage::find($id);
        $MailMessage->delete();
    }

    public function saveMailMessage($request)
    {
        $MailMessage = new Message($request->all());
        $MailMessage->save();
        return $MailMessage;
    }

    public function setOAuthAccessToken($accessToken)
    {

    }

    public function updateMailMessage($request, $id) {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something wrong, you declare mailMessageRepository variable so you need to use $this->mailMessageRepository

```
public function __construct(mailmessageRepository $mailmessageRepository)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->MailMessageRepository = $mailmessageRepository;
}
```

try this

```
public function __construct(MailMessageRepository $mailmessageRepository)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->mailMessageRepository = $mailmessageRepository;
}
```

and try replace all $this->MailMessageRepository to $this->mailMessageRepository in your code

Comment: I received the same error :(

Arguments
"Class app\Repositories\MailMessageRepository does not exist"

Comment: use app\Repositories\MailMessageRepository
instead try App\Repositories\MailMessageRepository;

Comment: or you should try composer dump-autoload

Comment: now I received this error
ReflectionException
Class App\Repositories\MailMessageRepository does not exist
Previous exceptions
syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ';' (0)

After change to App\Repositories\MailMessageRepository;
and dump-autoload too

Comment: please check your path App\Repositories\MailMessageRepository.php

Comment: Friend, I have deleted all functions of my MailMessageRepository and I deleted functions with this repository in MailMessageController and my page returned to normal

my other repository has functions with colored letters, this repository does not mark the colored functions, and it has exactly the same structure, I don't understand the problem